# Making a Password Generator code by creating a new function and want to use if else

Tags: python, function, if-statement

```
import random
import string


a = int(input("How may characters in letter format password"))
def random_char(y):
       return ''.join(random.choice(string.ascii_letters) for x in range(y))

print (random_char(a))
```

This works fine, But what if want to give a user choice, suppose if i press one it should call letters, if i press 2, it should call password in lowercase

can anyone help me or guide me or suggest me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could make this much more sophisticated and foolproof, but to answer your specific question, you could create another function calling `.lower()` and have some if statement functionality.

```
import random
import string


a = int(input("How may characters in letter format password"))
b = int(input("Will the password be lowercase? Type 1 for Yes and 2 for No."))

def random_char(y):
       return ''.join(random.choice(string.ascii_letters) for x in range(y))


def random_char_lower(y):
       return ''.join(random.choice(string.ascii_letters).lower() for x in range(y))


if b == 1:
    print (random_char(a))
elif b == 2:
    print (random_char_lower(a))
else: print ("Invalid Selection")
```

Comment: Can you explain me why for x in range is used ?? As i'am a pure fresher. Also as you're a programmer, Can you suggest me how can i improve ?

Comment: @Bhavyalodaya x represents one letter and y represents all of the letters, in others words the full "word" or "phrase" or "random group of generated letters" in this case. Essentially, these randomizations occur letter-by-letter for each x in range(y). If this helped you get to the solution, then please accept my answer as the solution.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a menu driven system as follows,

1. generate
2. lower

   `option = int(input("select menu option")`

   `if option == 1: call your generate function here elif option == 2: call the function, but this time use the .lower() method on your final string`

Is this what you mean?

Answer (score 1):

```
import random
import string


a = int(input("How may characters in letter format password"))
def random_char_l(y):
       return ''.join(random.choice([x.lower() for x in string.ascii_letters]) 

def random_char_u(y):
    return ''.join(random.choice(string.ascii_letters) for x in range(y))

choice = int(input("1 for lower, 2 for upper: "))

if choice == 1:
    print(random_char_l(a))
else:
    print(random_char_u(a)
```

Bit of a sloppy implementation but it should do the job.

Comment: Error in first def random_char_u (y) --- You missed for x in range(y))